# How to construct a Soap Envelope manually using TXMLDocument (Delphi 2006)

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2006, txmldocument

I've been having this problem for a long time now and I cannot solve it my self. I've tried searching Google, Bing and stackOverflow too? No luck...

I'm trying to construct a soap header manually using the TXMLDocument component of Delphi 2006:

...
...
...
  
  
...
...
...

What I'm doing is that I'm constructing a new Element called 'soap:Envelope'. In this new element I'm creating three attribtues called: 'xmlns:soap', 'xmlns:xsd' and 'xmlns:xsi'.

When I'm trying to write a value in any of the three attributes then I'm getting the error below:

Attempt to modify a read-only node.

Does any one know how to do this task using the TXMLDocument?

/Brian

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header>
...
...
...
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
...
...
...
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works fine here:

```
procedure WriteSoapFile;
var
  Document: IXMLDocument;
  Envelope: IXMLNode;
  Body: IXMLNode;
begin
  Document := NewXMLDocument;
  Envelope := Document.AddChild('soap:Envelope');
  Envelope.Attributes['xmlns:soap'] := 'schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
  Envelope.Attributes['xmlns:xsd']  := 'w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';
  Envelope.Attributes['xmlns:xsi']  := 'w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
  Body := Envelope.AddChild('soap:Body');
  Document.SaveToFile('Test.xml');
end;
```

You should be able to use `TXMLDocument` instead of `IXMLDocument`, it is just a component wrapper around the interface.

Comment: Wow. That works. Thank you so much!!! I was trying to set the value using the property NodeValue := ....;

I was using the following semantic (very simplyfied): MyNode := Document.CreateNode(....); MyNode.NodeValue := ....; /Brian

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, it uses DeclareNamespace to declare namespaces:

```
procedure WriteSoapFile;
const
  NS_SOAP = 'schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
var
  Document: IXMLDocument;
  Envelope: IXMLNode;
  Body: IXMLNode;
begin
  Document := NewXMLDocument;
  Envelope := Document.CreateElement('soap:Envelope', NS_SOAP);
  Envelope.DeclareNamespace('soap', NS_SOAP);
  Envelope.DeclareNamespace('xsd', 'w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
  Envelope.DeclareNamespace('xsi', 'w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
  Body := Envelope.AddChild('Body');
  Document.DocumentElement := Envelope;
  Document.SaveToFile('Test.xml');
end;
```

Based on the code provided in [How to set the prefix of a document element in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119314/how-to-set-the-prefix-of-a-document-element-in-delphi)

Comment: Thanks for this solution too. I love you guys (o; Thank you. Thank you. Thank you!!!

Comment: Since the question was only about the header I did not bother with setting namespaces, but your solution is of course a bit cleaner.